Access was blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request fails access control check
I get the following error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'client' from origin 'server' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
In short, the server response is blocked by CORS policy. I added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, but for some reason I still get this error.
The site is hosted on netlify, from which requests are sent to vercel.
Vercel uses js and node, on netlify it uses React
versel.json

{
  "version": 2,
 
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "./index.js",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
       
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}

index.js
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const path = require('path');
import cors from 'cors';
const server = jsonServer.create();

const router = jsonServer.router(path.resolve(__dirname, 'db.json'));

server.use(jsonServer.defaults({}));
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser);


server.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        const db = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'db.json'), 'UTF-8'));
        const { users = [] } = db;

        const userFromBd = users.find(
            (user) => user.username === username && user.password === password,
        );

        if (userFromBd) {
            return res.json(userFromBd);
        }

        return res.status(403).json({ message: 'User not found' });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
    }
});


// eslint-disable-next-line
server.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: 'AUTH ERROR' });
    }

    next();
});

server.use(router);


server.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('server is running on 8000 port');
});

I tried adding headers, changing the index.js configuration.
